# Murder rate in the last years of Weimar Republic 1927-1933

Tags: germany, weimar-republic

I am writing a paper about mortality during the last years of Weimar Republic, namely 1928-1933. Presenting the data in Berlin, scholars wondered about the reason why the figures about people dead by murder and manslaughter (**Mord und Totschlag** in German) were that high. During the period 1927-1937, homicide rate has its peak at 1.9 every 100,000 people in 1932, which reported to Germany entire population of that year is around 1249 murders in a year.

I made a Google search about crime in Weimar Republic and I actually found out that high level of crimes were mostly perceived rather than actual. Indeed, there has been three serial killers during that period and a bunch of political murders but nobody consider the numbers particularly astonishing. References: "Rethinking the Weimar Republic: Authority and Authoritarianism, 1916-1936" by Anthony McElligott and "A short History of the Weimar Republic", Colin Storer

**EDIT**: I found this graph from Pinker (2011), which actually shows that Germany, even murder rate is low in absolute has the second highest value after Italy in 1920s-1930s

[image]

Still wandering why anyway.

Is anybody aware of the reason why murder rates were that high in Germany in that period? Or does anybody know sources, which may give an explanation?

Comment: 1.9 is supposed to be high? Here in the US the rate today is 5.35. The average rate in this entire hemisphere is freaking 16.3. The average rate in Europe is 3.0. Sure the rate is lower in Germany today, but that seems more like a case of Germany's rate today being super low.

Comment: You might look at the *unnatural death rate* vs. the *conviction rate*. A dead body only becomes a murder victim if a suspect is convicted of murder.

Comment: Well formed question - could you cite the article about perceived vs actual crime?  Or the serial killers?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace It's from a couple of books "Rethinking the Weimar Republic: Authority and Authoritarianism, 1916-1936" by Anthony McElligott pp.117-119 and "A short History of the Weimar Republic", Colin Storer

Comment: Your understanding is unclear to me: do you want primary sources on the data, primary sources on the contemporary interpretation of Mord and Totschlag rates or a historical analysis with current perspective? Please also clarify (& perhaps quote) "scholars were struck". The quotes you named in response to Mark's comment are better served in the question itself with an [edit].

Comment: @LangLangC Thanks for your comments, I edited and hope its clearer now

Comment: With Germany's history as it is, why *wouldn't* the murder rate be slightly higher than in the countries that did not lose a war and therefor did not have to pay crippling reparations? I'm not surprised to see a higher murder rate from a country where people are unhappy, largely unemployed and don't have enough of anything to go round. Could you explain why you'd expect it to be the same as those of the victors?

Answer (score 2):

During the Weimar Republic the society in Germany was extremly divided. So there were also quite a lot of political murders and actual firefights between right and left wingers. I think this should also be taken in account.

In German, an article about political murders mainly in Bavaria, where quit a few politians got murdered. Then there was for example the case, when 21 members of some church group were murdered by some right winger, probably mistaken for members of some left wing organisation. In a society where usually not that much people get murdered, those political crimes can actually push the numbers quite a bit.

At the end you'll find additional [sources](https://www.historisches-lexikon-bayerns.de/Lexikon/Politische_Morde_(Weimarer_Republik))

There's a [prezi](https://prezi.com/rwjq83wes7jc/politische-morde-in-der-weimarer-republik/) with some of the murders of known politicians (also some additional sources)

Comment: Your links might or might not answer the question. However [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please edit your answer to improve its quality. Thanks!